# Spring Data JPA sort giving inconsistent answers

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, jpa

We have a Spring Boot App running on several servers (DEV, QA, and PROD). We used a JPA Repository architecture to implement accesses to our database. Everything is running well and then we found something that makes no sense.

We use the following URL:
`PRODURL:9090/locations/search/findByStreetNumberStartingWithAndApartmentNumberStartingWithAndStreetNameStartingWithAndZipCode_CityStartingWithAndZipCode_StateProvStartingWithAndZipCode_ZipCodeStartingWithAndCompany_NameStartingWith?stNumber=100&aptNumber=&street=N%20College&city=&state=&zip=&company=BREV&page=3&size=20&sort=streetNumber&projection=detail`

and it points to 7 pages of locations - every location has the same street number; they vary by apartment number.

In PROD,

> page=0 returns items 1,2,3,...19,20.
>
> page=1 returns items 21,20,19...3,2.
>
> Page=2 returns 41,42...59,60.
>
> Page=3 and page=4 return the same as page=1, and
>
> page=5 or 6 return the correct data.

The exact same code deployed to PROD returns the correct data on each page.

In DEV, nearly the same code gives the same error as PROD on page=1; the other pages are correct.

Question: is there a bug in Spring Data or JPA repository? These results are repeatable. Does it have to do with sorting on a variable that doesn't change? (That doesn't explain why the same code works differently when deployed to different servers.)

UPDATE: going to sort=streetNumber,aptNumber does seem to give us correct answers. Yes, each deployed version hits independent databases, but all three databases were synced up two days ago.

Comment: If you add a secondary sort on apartment number or the primary key does it affect the behavior?

Comment: Same version of the database?  What happens if you point your local app at the PROD database?

Comment: What is the query that is being called while hitting those url's on different servers..compare those and you'll get an idea of what goes wrong